# Free tool like Snagit which can capture scrolling Window?

Tags: screen-capture

[Snagit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snagit) can capture scrolling windows like in a browser. Is there a free capture tool for Windows which can do the same kind of capturing?

I am **not** looking for a generic capture tool. I need one which can capture a full web page even if it extends several screens vertically.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [free version of **FastStone Capture**](http://www.aplusfreeware.com/categories/mmedia/FastStoneCapture.html) will capture a scrolling web page. Works best with IE but also works with FF (it scrolls the window very slowly) and kinda works with Chrome (page is OK but it messes up the the scroll bars).

There's also [**PicPick**](http://picpick.wiziple.net/) (use the 'Capture Window Control' command) which works with IE and Firefox  though won't scroll in Chrome.

Comment: never thought of FastStone, while it isn't as easy to use as Aviari or indeed Web Screen Capture it has the advantage of What you see is what you get. WSC and Aviari will capture a website from a given URL alright, but in case of a forum website like superuser.com, you'll get the 'unregistered user' version ... +1

Comment: @Molly. It's a screen capture not a site downloader if that's what you mean.

Comment: `FastStone` not working for me in Windows 7 - July 2011

Comment: PicPick is the right tool to do this at the time of speaking 19 July 2011 and in Windows 7. The feature is `Scrolling Windows`

Comment: FastStone Capture 5.3 worked great in IE8, but was not able to properly capture in FF 6.0.2, looks like I need to update FF.  Using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: PicPick worked very good and has many other tools, Just installed and I like it.

Answer (score 4):

I use the free **[ScreenGrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146)** add-on for Firefox, which can capture a selection of a page, the visible portion, or *the whole page* past the scroll area.  In addition, it can also copy to clipboard, or save as JPG or PNG.  I've been using it for over a year now with no ill effects -- it's great.

Comment: This works perfectly for me

Comment: not working with new versions of firefox... .

Comment: According to the author, ScreenGrab is no longer maintained. Bummer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Firefox, then [**FireShot**](http://screenshot-program.com/fireshot/) might be what you're looking for.

[**Web Screen Capture**](http://www.webscreencapture.com/) - a free stand-alone web site and web page screenshot and thumbnail utility.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Aviary.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20181211003445/https://www.aviary.com/), an online application that can do screen captures (region, visible, or whole pages) and online editing. They have an online video about their service [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181211003445/https://www.aviary.com/).

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/images/t/33557/1245640098))</sub>

Their free service does what you need. It's all online, no software to install. I use a Firefox extension which makes it really easy to use.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two of the best I have found (that have scrolling web page capture) for Windows and both freeware are:

- [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/)
- [SnapCrab](http://www.fenrir-inc.com/uk/snapcrab/)

[SnapCrab](http://www.downloadcrew.co.uk/article/28952-snapcrab) was reviewed by DownloadCrew and their verdict was that it was a serious competitor to Snagit.

With the option to download from there as well.

If you want a portable tool with all the features that you can carry around on a USB stick I would highly recommend [PicPick Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/picpick-portable).

Comment: Greenshot doesn't support capturing scrolling windows (tested as of latest release 1.2.9.98-RC2).