# Screen capture program for Windows to capture scrolling content area of web page + other components of browser window

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, browser-addons, screen-capture

I am looking for something similiar to [Free tool like Snagit which can capture scrolling Window?](https://superuser.com/questions/33244/free-tool-like-snagit-which-can-capture-scrolling-window) and [Free Windows software for full-screen (including scrolling) screenshots](https://superuser.com/questions/265437/free-windows-software-for-full-screen-including-scrolling-screenshots), but also capable of including other components in the browser window itself in the same screenshot.

Note: I am specifically interested in the title bar and address bar for Internet Explorer (in the case of browser-specific solutions)

Answer (score 0):

No luck here. PicPick, FireShot, DuckCapture, etc are all free options that capture scrolling windows but none of them capture the URL/Title bar at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

For free software would suggest you the same what @Dan the Man told you, but if you want a browser specific plugin, you can make use of plugins like Capture Fox or Screen Grab, or if you're willing to buy a software, you should go for Microfoft Expression Studio 4 Ultimate. It has everything you need.

Answer (score -1):

A screen recorder would do just that. If you know how to edit video it should work just fine. [Here](http://camstudio.org/) is a free one.

Comment: This is not good enough, please refer to the questions that I referenced to get a better idea of what I am looking for.